Period of products of sine and cosine
I am trying to show that the smallest period of $sin(\theta)cos^n(\theta)$ is $\pi$ if $n$ is odd and $2\pi$ if $n$ is even. For $n=0,1$ this is quite simple, but I cannot seem to find a way to show this for $n=2$. I can show that $2 \pi$ is a period, but not that is the shortest period. Ideally this would involve showing that a factor of $cos^2(\theta)$ leaves the smallest period unchanged (if it is $\pi$ or $2\pi$), then the higher orders would simply follow from this fact. Is there any way to prove this?

We have
$$\sin(x)\cos^n(x).$$
Then:
$$\sin(x+\pi)\cos^n(x+\pi) = (-1)^{n+1}\sin(x)\cos^n(x).$$
For odd $n$:
$$(-1)^{n+1}\sin(x)\cos^n(x)=\sin(x)\cos^n(x).$$
For even $n$:
$$(-1)^{n+1}\sin(x)\cos^n(x)=-\sin(x)\cos^n(x) \implies \sin(x+2\pi)\cos^n(x+2\pi) = \sin(x)\cos^n(x).$$

Sorry for poor MathJax
